# Integrating factor for DE of the form DE $f(xy) ydx+g(xy) xdy=0$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, integrating-factor

I know that IF is of the form $$ \frac{1}{Mx-Ny} $$

But I couldn't find a formal proof anywhere. So far I could do the following:

$f(xy)x=P$ and $g(xy)y=Q$

$(\mu P)_y = (\mu Q)_x$

$f\mu + y f_y\mu+ xyf\mu_y = g\mu + xf_x\mu+xyf\mu_x$

Comment: Change the free variables from $(x,y)$ to $(x,u=xy)$. Then $0=f(u)x^{-1}u\,dx+g(u)x\,d(x^{-1}u)$ could show a more obvious structure. It should become linear in $x$.

Comment: @LutzLehmann I managed to get something like this: 

$$ u ( f(u)-g(u) ) dx + g(u) du = 0 $$

Comment: @DominicJoseph  check your calculation because I think a factor  $x$ is missing $xg(u)du$

Comment: @user577215664 It was a typing mistake. The calculation is fine

Comment: Ok thats good then  @DominicJoseph

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$u ( f(u)-g(u) ) dx + xg(u) du = 0$$
Divide by the integrating factor :$$\mu=xu ( f(u)-g(u) )=x^2y ( f(xy)-g(xy) )$$
$$\mu =x(xM-yN)$$

Then the DE becomes exact.
$$\dfrac {dx}{x}+   \dfrac {g(u)} {u ( f(u)-g(u) )} du = 0$$